# php/mongodb: how does references work in php?

Tags: php, reference, mongodb

i asked this in the mongodb user-group, but was not satisfied with the answer, so -- maybe someone at stackoverflow can enlighten me:

**EDIT:**

i've re-written my question, because apparently it wasn't clear, what was happening -- please try my test-code before answering. thanks!

```
<?php

// test: a
$data = array('x' => 1);

function a(&$data) {
    $m = new mongo();
    $c = $m->selectDB('test')->selectCollection('test');

    $c->insert($data);
}

a($data);
print_r($data);

// test: b
$data = array('x' => 1);

function b($data) {
    $m = new mongo();
    $c = $m->selectDB('test')->selectCollection('test');

    $c->insert($data);
}

b($data);
print_r($data);

// test: c
$data = array('x' => 1);

function c(&$data) {
    $data['_id'] = new MongoId();
}

c($data);
print_r($data);

// test: d
$data = array('x' => 1);

function d($data) {
    $data['_id'] = new MongoId();
}

d($data);
print_r($data);

?>
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [x] => 1
)

Array
(
    [x] => 1
    [_id] => MongoId Object
        (
        )

)

Array
(
    [x] => 1
    [_id] => MongoId Object
        (
        )

)

Array
(
    [x] => 1
)
```

my question: why does pass-by-reference apparently work different for mongo insert compared to my plain php function call?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kristina Chodorow, the maintainer of the mongoDB php extension, wrote up a nice article in her blog about this issue:

http://www.snailinaturtleneck.com/blog/2011/09/07/more-php-internals-references/

in my opinion it clarifies how things work in php, i still think that references in php are really awkward ...

Answer (score 0):

When you have something like `$ref = &$someVar`.  `$ref` now refers to the **value at** `$someVar`.

**EDIT:**

The [MongoDB Manual at PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongodb.php) says:

**Example** #1 MongoCollection::insert()  _id example
Inserting an object will add an _id field to it, *unless it is passed by reference*.

```
<?php

$a = array('x' => 1);
$collection->insert($a);
var_dump($a)

$b = array('x' => 1);
$ref = &$b;
$collection->insert($ref);
var_dump($ref);

?>
```

Comment: yes i know. if i then pass $ref to a function, which accepts the parameter as reference (like my test function), than $ref ($someVar) can be enhanced with more data. ... but the mongodb-insert does not work this way. my question: why does the mongodb-insert method behaves like it behaves?

Comment: babiker, i understand, what the documentation is telling me. thanks for your help, but it does not answer my question: i don't understand the sense behind this behaviour. who is doing the magic behind the scenes? who keeps the _id out of $ref and why does this behaviour differ from the behaviour of my plain php test?